# How do I move my sites to a child theme without loosing customisation?

Tags: customization, themes, child-theme

How can I make my websites that do not use a child theme, to use one, but not loose customisation, such as MENU, WIDGETS, and many other available in the theme at the time of change. This is something really needed when dealing with many sites without a child theme, recreating all the sites structure with menu and widgets can be a huge time consumer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Each theme has one config which is associated with options. When you move theme you just have to move option in the database to the key of the theme. Tell me whether this could help you or not. Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where are those configs located? Is there a special place for this?